# How to remove <br> from prettyPhoto hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

On my website I have several prettyPhoto galleries and I have noticed that in all of them when the mouse hovers over a photo, the "title" tag of the photo displays. This includes some `<br>` tags that then show up in the hover and it looks pretty bad. I have searched and tried a bunch of alterations to the jquery but cant find a fix. Does anyone know how to remove the `<br>` from the hover?

An example of the html is:

```
<article class="span3 box3">
  <div class="thumb-pad4 maxheight">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <figure><a href="img/p1.jpg" alt="job | Person 1" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery3]" title="
<br>
<br>
<br>
Person1 joined __ in 2015 as a ___.  In this role, ...
<br>
<br>
Person 1 graduated from ____ and wishes he were better at code> 
<img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="job | p1">
</a>
</figure>
  <div class="caption">
    <a href="#">Person 1<br>
Job Function</a>                                    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</article>
```

What appears then on the hover is:

```
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
Person1 joined __ in 2015 as a ___.  In this role, ...
<br>
<br>
Person 1 graduated from ____ and wishes he were better at code
```

Comment: Can you do a screenshot of your issue please ?

Comment: Or, even better, provide some code that replicates the problem?

Comment: You need to provide some code, it's impossible for us to guess what'd be going wrong. I know most of us wish we were mutants with the ability to read minds, but unfortunately we are no Charles Xavier :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrettyPhoto uses the attribute `title` to add a caption to the photo when you click or hover over it.

You need to add some CSS to your page that adds spacing above and below the caption when it is displayed in "click mode". From looking at how prettyPhoto works, the caption text is put inside a `div` with `class="pp_description"`.

Therefore, remove all the `<br>` tags from your HTML, and **instead add a CSS rule**:

```
.pp_description {
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    /* line-height: 3em; if you want spacing between each line of text in the caption */
}
```

Comment: You can change the `em` values to whatever you desire. Each `1em` represents the height of a "standard" line of text. You could also use `px`.

Comment: Just as a general rule, always use CSS to add spacing instead of using `<br>` tags.

Comment: this worked great and was a quick fix - thanks for your help @4castle I inherited this site and am trying  to fix/update. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.replace()` with an regex (without it you would just replace the FIRST match only. You need a "greedy-regex")

[RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

e.g:

```
<script>
    $('.my-class')
        .on('mouseenter', function() {
            var originalTitle = $(this).attr('title');

            $('.my-class').attr('data-original-title', originalTitle);
            $('.my-class').attr('title', title.replace(/<br>/g,''));
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function() {
            var originalTitle = $(this).attr('data-original-title');

            $('.my-class').attr('title', originalTitle);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This would fix the problem, but is probably unnecessary until we learn more. The best solution is probably just to manually remove the `<br>` tags from the html source code.

Comment: when I do that though I lose the spacing I need in the gallery once the image is clicked and opened ... I tried using <p></p> but that obviously had the same result

Comment: @CodinglyClueless - check my Edit

Comment: @zeropublix thanks for your help and for the info above - definitely something to read and learn. Im going with the css below though as its a quick fix and something I already know how to do. Thanks for the time and help!